# H2 convert date to milliseconds

Tags: sql, database, h2

I am trying to convert date in H2 database into milliseconds.

In order to perform some calculation with milliseconds between two dates, i am trying to convert dates to milliseconds, but i can't find any function that would help me in h2 documentation.

Is there any function that can help me, or should i just create custom H2 function for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, i just figured out how to do this.

```
select datediff('ms', '1970-01-01', DATE_COLUMN) as DATE_IN_MS from TABLE;
```